# ValueError: invalid literal in Python code from int() on empty string

Tags: python

I have this as a part of my code in Python, and each time I run my code I have the same error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

The code is:

```
freq = 0
for line in text:                       
    matchObj = re.search(r"(\W*)(/freq\W+)(\d*)", line, re.M|re.I)
    if matchObj :
        if freq < matchObj.group(3):
            freq = matchObj.group(3)
f.write("| "+template.format("XYZ".rstrip(),int(freq))+"\n")
y = int(freq)
```

The problem occurs on the 7th line, in `f.write(...)`.

Comment: Your `freq` seems to be an empty string

Comment: `(\d*)` match the empty string, which is invalid for `int()`.

Comment: If `\d*` (zero or more digits) matches *no digits*, then `.group(3) == ''`. Switch to `\d+` (one or more digits) instead.

Comment: @jonrsharpe As RE are greedy by default, if `(\d*)` match an empty string here, `(\d+)` will not match anything for the OP data (at least for one input line)

Comment: @SylvainLeroux yes, that's correct; the line won't match, so the attempt to convert to `int` won't be made. Is that not the correct behaviour?

Comment: Line 7 `f.write...` isn't indented, so you're not doing this every time you go around the for-loop, only once at the end, i.e. only output the maximum freq observed. If that's not what you intended, you need to indent line 7 inside the for-loop.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Maybe. I would have said that the regular expression was simply not correct for the given input data. But without more feedback from the OP this will be hard to tell.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you had `ValueError` is because `int` cannot convert an empty string to the integer. In this case you'd need to either check the content of the string before conversion, or except an error:

```
try:
   int('')
except ValueError:
   pass      # or whatever
```

Answer (score 1):

Evidently, `freq == ''`. This is because the third group in your regex, `(\d*)`, can capture *zero or more digits*. If it captures zero digits, then the group is an empty string and the `int` conversion fails.

To fix this, change the regex to capture *one or more digits*, using `(\d+)`. Alternatively, if something else should happen in the zero digits case, add an explicit handler for it: `if matchObj.group(3) == '':`.

Note also that you are comparing `freq`, initially the integer `0`, with `matchObj.group(3)` **before** it's converted to an integer. I think you probably want:

```
freq = 0
for line in text:                       
    matchObj = re.search(r"(\W*)(/freq\W+)(\d+)", line, re.M|re.I)
    if matchObj:
        new_freq = int(matchObj.group(3)) 
        if freq < new_freq:
            freq = new_freq
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you exactly what the problem is: you are trying to convert an empty string to an integer. In your regular expression, `\d*` can match *zero or more* digits, and that's exactly what it has done -- matched zero digits.